# performance of calculations on large flattened dictionary with implied hierarchy

Tags: python, performance

Given a dictionary structured like this:

```
{'guy1_arm_param1':23.0, 'guy1_arm_param2_low':2.0, 'guy1_arm_param2_high':3.0, 'guy1_arm_param3':20.0,
'guy1_leg_param1':40.0, 'guy1_leg_param2_low':2.0, 'guy1_leg_param2_high':3.0, 'guy1_leg_param3':20.0,
'guy2_arm_param1':23.0, 'guy2_arm_param2_low':2.0, 'guy2_arm_param2_high':3.0, 'guy2_arm_param3':20.0,
'guy2_leg_param1':40.0, 'guy2_leg_param2_low':2.0, 'guy2_leg_param2_high':3.0, 'guy2_leg_param3':20.0,
'another_guy_param1':3.0}
```

What the most efficient way to make a function which will go through and pull out the parameters for a given 'guy' and make a calculation with them?
For example:

```
def full_guy_function(given_dict, guy):
    d = unflatten(given_dict)
    guy_functions = list()
    guy_dict = {}
    for body_part in d[guy].keys():
        param1 = d[guy][body_part]['param1']
        param3 = d[guy][body_part]['param3']
        for k, v in d[guy][body_part]['param2'].iteritems():
            guy_functions.append(get_function_for_part(param1, v, param3))  
    full_guy_function = sum(guy_functions)
    return full_guy_function

def get_function_for_part(param1, param2, param3):
    x = [x for x in range(0,100)]
    x = numpy.array(x)
    return param3**(x*param1/param2)

# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037503/python-unflatten-dict
def unflatten(dictionary):
    resultDict = dict()
    for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
        parts = key.split('_')
        d = resultDict
        for part in parts[:-1]:
            if part not in d:
                d[part] = dict()
            d = d[part]
        d[parts[-1]] = value
    return resultDict
```

I feel like looping through and making other dictionaries etc. is horribly inefficient.  (this is a big main dictionary, and this function will be called every couple milliseconds.)
I tried to do this using objects which was much more easily understood, but the hierarchical objects cannot be read from different processes than the ones that are using and writing to them. So, I am stuck with trying to make a massive flattened dictionary like this and calculating the results on both sides of the processes.

If this type of operation has to be done every couple of milliseconds on large sets of data, is it better to do with a database?

Comment: You might be better off going through the entire dictionary item by item rather than rebuilding a new unflattened dictionary each time, but it's going to be horribly slow either way. A database is built for this sort of thing, but I don't know how it will react to a new query every couple of milliseconds. I think you need to step back and consider a different data structure.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRansom Those are good insights. What type of data structure do you think would work well here?  I thought objects worked well but they seem to be completely incompatible with the future of electronics and multiple core systems.
I also thought of just making a hierarchy of dictionaries, but that is incompatible with multiple core systems as well (not picklable).

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with multi-threaded Python programming or pickling to be able to make a concrete suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Better later than never...

I suggest you to use `python-benedict`, it is [open-source on GitHub](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-benedict) (I am the author).

Installation: `pip install python-benedict`

Just test how the flatten dict will be:

```py
from benedict import benedict

data = benedict({
    'guy1_arm_param1':23.0, 'guy1_arm_param2_low':2.0, 'guy1_arm_param2_high':3.0, 'guy1_arm_param3':20.0,
    'guy1_leg_param1':40.0, 'guy1_leg_param2_low':2.0, 'guy1_leg_param2_high':3.0, 'guy1_leg_param3':20.0,
    'guy2_arm_param1':23.0, 'guy2_arm_param2_low':2.0, 'guy2_arm_param2_high':3.0, 'guy2_arm_param3':20.0,
    'guy2_leg_param1':40.0, 'guy2_leg_param2_low':2.0, 'guy2_leg_param2_high':3.0, 'guy2_leg_param3':20.0,
    'another_guy_param1':3.0,
})
data_unflatten = data.unflatten()
print(data_unflatten.dump())
```

Your code:

```py
from benedict import benedict

def full_guy_function(given_dict, guy):
    b = benedict(given_dict)
    d = b.unflatten()
    guy_functions = []
    guy_dict = {}
    for guy_key, guy_val in d.items():
        param1 = guy_val['param1']
        param3 = guy_val['param3']
        for k, v in guy_val['param2'].items():
            guy_functions.append(get_function_for_part(param1, v, param3))  
    full_guy_function = sum(guy_functions)
    return full_guy_function

def get_function_for_part(param1, param2, param3):
    x = [x for x in range(0,100)]
    x = numpy.array(x)
    return param3**(x*param1/param2)
```